# Getting Error " Expecting body class" in Kotlin while writing function for requesting json objects

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I am writing a function for requesting a objects and strings from Youtube Data API
here is the code

```
private fun gettingRequest(x:String)
{
    val url :String = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + x+
            "&key=API_KEY&part=snippet"

    val jsonObject = object : JsonObjectRequest( url,null ,Response.Listener {

        val success  = it.getBoolean("success")
        if(success){

            val items = it.getJSONObject("items")
            val uid = items.getString("id")
            val snippet = items.getJSONObject("snippet")
            val title_video = snippet.getString("title")
            val description = snippet.getString("description")
            val thumbnails = snippet.getJSONObject("thumbnails")
            val default = thumbnails.getJSONObject("default")
            val thumbnailDetails = thumbnail(default.getString("url"),
                default.getInt("width"),default.getInt("height"))
            details.add(data_math(uid,title_video,description,thumbnailDetails))
        }

    },
    Response.ErrorListener {

    })
    

} // error here
```

the error shows Expecting a class body
Please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `object :`. You seem to be wanting to instantiate a `JsonObjectRequest` object, not an anonymous subclass of it (for which the body is missing).